# How do I dim background when Modal is displayed in react-native

Tags: react-native, background, modal-dialog

I have got the modal as expected but I could not dim the background.

I also tried `backdropColor = {'green'}`  `backdropOpacity = {1}` but still the background exists.
I need help for this. Below is my code:

```
import Modal from "react-native-modal";
    <View 
          style={styles.MainContainer}>
            <Modal
                backdropColor={'green'}
                backdropOpacity= {1}
                animationType={"slide"}
                visible={this.state.ModalVisibleStatus}
                onRequestClose={ ()=>{ this.ShowModalFunction(!this.state.ModalVisibleStatus)}}>

              <View style={{ flex:1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                <View style={styles.ModalInsideView}>
                  <Text 
                      style={styles.TextStyle}>
                      Enter the Number of Tickets to be Printed. 
                   </Text>

                    <NumberSpinner
                    packageCount={this.state.tickets} min={0} max={20}
                    onChange={this.ticketsCount}
                  />

                 <Button  
                      title="Print Tickets" 
                       onPress={() => { this.ShowModalFunction(!this.state.ModalVisibleStatus)}}/>
              </View>
            </View>
          </Modal>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are using the *wrong prop* to trigger the `Modal`. As mentioned in the [docs](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-modal) , you need to use **`isVisible`** to show the modal and not `visible`.

Therefore for the `backdropColor` and `backdropOpacity` to work you need to change your code as

```
<Modal
       backdropColor={'green'}
       backdropOpacity= {1}
       animationType={"slide"}
       isVisible={this.state.ModalVisibleStatus}
```

Comment: Just FYI to anyone viewing this answer. This answer is for the 'react-native-modal' component and not the original Modal component from the 'react-native' library.

Answer (score 4):

Please note the **Accepted answer** is for library `react-native-modal`.

For dimming/blurring the background of `modal` of basic React Native component.

Enclose all your content inside `<Modal>` under a `<View>` and provide a `backgroundColor` and `opacity` to the `style` as below:

```
<Modal visible animationType="slide">
   <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5)'}}>
     {/* children components*/}
   </View>
 </Modal>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `isVisible` prop instead of `visible`. 
Refer [docs](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-modal) for exact props.